# How to get special character ' in POST php

Tags: php

When i get the POST data from form . 
This is my html of a particular input field .

```
<input type="text" title="Nick Name" data-optional="1" value="" name="FedEx_small_dropship_nickname" placeholder="Nick Name" id="FedEx_small_dropship_nickname">
```

when i add the input like **nick 'o' compton** it make it **nick 'o' compton** means it does not read ' sign and make it ' but i want to store ' in db . Any body please help . 
Regards

Comment: You will have to post your PHP code as well, but it is most likely that you should be using prepared statements which will solve this and a few other problems.

Comment: just use prepared statements in your insertions so that you wouldn't need to make any string manipulations

Comment: You should really go work through some beginner's tutorials that explain this kind of stuff.

Answer (score -2):

while inserting to DB use:
htmlspecialchars($data_var, ENT_QUOTES)

and later on when you display this data back to users:
htmlspecialchars_decode($data_var, ENT_QUOTES);